# Can I get windows 7 like window resizing on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display

Windows 7 has a nice new feature for moving around windows.

The one that I am particularly interested in is: 
*Windows Key + Left/Right : Move the window to the left or right of the screen, or over to a second monitor.*

But, *Windows Key + Up: Maximize the current window* and *Windows Key + Down: Restore or minimize the current window.* are also quite useful.

Is there anyway that I can get this functionality in OS? Preferably replacing the windows key with Command Key.

Answer (score 25):

### [Shift It](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt)

If you [read this Article](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/04/19/shiftit-brings-windows-7-aero-snap-to-your-mac/) I think you get what you want.

[image]

Comment: I like that this is free and open source. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: Can you add the name of the app and a direct link to the project site?  It will make it easier for future reference :)

Comment: Great find by the way!

Comment: The provided link is a little old, the project is now hosted on github, you can get the binaries there now. Link: https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt

Comment: Works great on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Article Link no longer links to an article.

Comment: Direct link binaries and source: https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt/releases. Version 1.6.6 works under macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.2).

Answer (score 10):

Two excellent, free tools:

- [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) is ultra-simple and lets you setup shortcut keys to all the typical window placement actions (fill left half of screen, fill top half, full screen, center, etc).
- [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) is very full featured and can do these keyboard shortcuts as well, but also lets you click and drag windows to "snap" to different regions of the screen. (And it has tons of other features, since it's original purpose was custom touchpad gestures).

Comment: Free. Solid: [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.net)

Comment: Uh yeah, that's what I listed above (including same link)

Comment: BetterTouchTool now requires the users to pay a license fee: https://www.boastr.net/btt-paid-faq/

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind paying, there's [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) from Irradiated Software, worth paying for IMO. Gives you lots of customizability.

If you just want the mouse windows resizing behaviour (dragging to the edges) from windows 7, there's [Cinch](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) from the same company.

Comment: +1 Cinch, though it's awkward on multiple monitor setups.

Answer (score 6):

There's a nice little app called [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/), that gives you a lot of control on windows resizing, including keyboard shortcuts similar to ones Win7 has. It's $14, but worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Divvy's the only one that makes it easy to size a window to a third of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few good alternatives (there are more):

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com)

[Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)

[Switche](http://kapeli.com/switche/)

Answer (score 1):

I used open source tool Slate (https://github.com/jigish/slate) for some years but moved recently all my configuration to non free "Keyboard Maestro". It's extremely flexible and settings can be edited using a tool instead of editing configuration files. It supports multiple screens and different setups better than anything else if've seen so far. Here's an example of pushing current window to the left half of main screen.

[image: Screenshot of definition of "Window to the left"]

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same thing since window management on Mac is not ideal. I use [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/mondomouse) (15$) for window sizing and control which I even like better than the Windows 7 model.