# Are there apps that enable "sticky" / "magnetic" / "docking" windows?

Tags: window-manager

I am looking for an app that makes windows stick to each other (if anybody used WinAmp back in the day you know what I mean).

This would be great when using apps that have several windows that I want to treat as one window - so if there is another method to accomplish this please do tell!

I found [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/) that makes windows snap to each other when moving via Zooom/2's keyboard shortcuts, but the windows do not stick to one another when you move one of them.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/alternative-way-to-move-windows-around-screen

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Comment: Thanks for the links, to the desktop management related questions, but I am not really interested in moving windows, just making them snap together.

Answer (score 2):

Divvy was my tool of choice for a while. It works like Zooom/2, so it will not fulfill your needs completely, just as the other suggestions [on this question](https://superuser.com/questions/117998/align-windows-to-a-grid-in-snow-leopard).

Stata 10 used to have 'magnetic' windows but the functionality disappeared, much to my sadness, in Stata 11. This change makes me believe that OS X must be resisting that functionality.

I think that the whole Exposé logic is working against that kind of functionality in the minds of many (but not mine: I am very sympathetic to your problem, I hate messy screens too).