# Autotiling for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

I love the big screen on the iMacs, but having to shape the applications so they don't overlap is not optimal. Is there a way to have an autotiling feature, so that with the touch of a (configurable mouse) button the windows get tiled automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not an exact duplicate, it basically covers Window Management, so I suggest you take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/557/can-i-get-windows-7-like-window-resizing-on-osx/563#563) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/850/advanced-window-manager-needed).