# Window management app on mac os x?

Tags: macos, window-manager, cinema-display

I currently use "Stay," and have tried other tools (haven't really loved any of them), but I am looking for a window management tool that does the following:

1. Store my window locations
2. Have a separate profile for different monitor setups
3. Allow me to quickly modify the location with hotkeys
4. Automatically load my default settings when I attach/detach a display

Any help would be great!

Comment: We've already had lots of window management questions. See [What Window Management Options Exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x) and [Can I get Windows 7-like resizing on Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/557/can-i-get-windows-7-like-window-resizing-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: Yeah, that is not what I am speaking off though. I guess my question is: Is there a more reliable app like "Stay" that I could get?

Comment: I know, which is why I didn't close this question.

Comment: [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x), [Tiling Window Manager for Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/162849/tiling-window-manager-for-mac-os-x), [multiple monitor software for Mac](http://superuser.com/questions/279036/muliple-monitor-software-for-mac), [Move windows around a desktop -- and to different desktops -- using only the keyboard?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28286/move-windows-around-a-desktop-and-to-different-desktops-using-only-the-key)

Comment: Some apps that allow resizing to custom bounds: [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/), [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy), [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)

Comment: There's a bunch of such tools listed in the answers [this question][1]. 


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29212/9058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used stay but I am using Moom (Apple store) and pretty happy with it. It stores windows positions and has configurable hotkeys. There is no automatic settings for different displays but since you can assign hotkeys to configuration is not a big issue.

It is very stable.

Comment: Hands down, Moom is the best - and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)

[image: Moom]

[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/)

[image: Divvy]

Answer (score 1):

I like [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/). It's super simple, just a few options, but they do the trick for me. I mostly just use left/right/upper/lower half and fullscreen (calling halves multiple times flips through several options).

[image: Spectacle options screenshot]

If you use [Homebrew-Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/), install by simply running:

```
brew cask install spectacle
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [DoublePane](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doublepane/id409737246?mt=12). It's $2.99 on Mac App Store.

Comment: its now $9.99 at app store.