# Move windows around a desktop -- and to different desktops -- using only the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish using only a keyboard:

1. **Move a window to different areas/corners of a desktop**
2. **Move a window to different desktops**
3. **Set/unset a window as shown/sticky on all desktops**

Yes, I know #3 could solve #2 by *stickying* a window, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>, then *unstickying* it, which would be acceptable, but i'm hoping for something a little more elegant :)

> NB, if 1..3 can be solved in AppleScript, that would be great because [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php) has been invaluable to tie an AppleScript to a global keyboard shortcut. However I don't think AppleScript can do this type of window location manipulation and a native Cocoa app may be required.

I really want to return to my *keyboard-only nirvana* but in my adoptive platform and shed Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many different sharewares out there that let you move windows around using shortcuts. Just look for window manager in the Mac App Store. I would recommend BetterTouchTool. It's a freeware that let's you customize just about anything. For example here is the shortcuts I have created for myself :

[image]

http://blog.boastr.net/

Comment: I did try BetterTouchTool a few weeks ago but found it to have issues in Lion which I hope would be fixed soon. I did however completely forget that it has the option move windows to corners, which satisfies #1, but cannot do #2 or #3 ...well, at least its donation-based ;)

Comment: After downgrading to Snow Leopard last weekend, BetterTouchTool has been working great for me!

Answer (score 7):

Moving windows to another space:

- [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) (still works for me in 10.8)
- [Spacey](http://most-advantageous.com/spacey/) (stopped working in 10.7)

Moving windows to another display:

- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)
- [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net)
- [Flexiglass](http://nulana.com/flexiglass)
- [Moom](http://target.georiot.com/Proxy.ashx?grid=598&GR_URL=http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=419330170%26mt=12)
- [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)
- [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)
- [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/)
- [Window Mover](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/window-mover/id412418002?mt=12)

Comment: Actually, it seems SizeUp offers the best options for #1 and #2. OTOH, coming fresh from OSS, I'm conflicted by supporting a "nagware" product... Thanks ;)

Comment: Divvy is another option, not quite as powerful as these but lightweight and useful.

Comment: Both SizeUp and Spacey don't work in Mountain Lion (according to their description). :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm still on Mountain Lion, so can't vouch for Mavericks. However...

[ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) is also worth a mention.  Keyboard only, but works great for me for corners, fullscreen and next screen functionality.

For configurable transparency and stickiness I use [Afloat](http://download.cnet.com/Afloat/3000-18487_4-97776.html) (source on [GitHub](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/))

Answer (score -1):

Moom is pretty awesome and will allow you to do #1 and #2.
https://manytricks.com/moom/

Comment: Do please add a few more details about Moom to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you hold down the green fullscreen button, it gives you the option to split/share the screen with a second window

Comment: The question asks for solutions ‘using only the keyboard’, can you expand your answer with how to perform this using keyboard input? How does this help move windows to different desktops?