# Any app that will automatically size and lock Finder windows?

Tags: macos, finder, windows

For several years I was Windows-only at work and used a great utility that resized and locked my Explorer windows.

I'm surprised I haven't come across this for the Mac as I am always repositioning, sizing my windows. Does anyone know if such an app exists?

Comment: Search on the [tag:window-manager] tag to get a sense of the options available. One is specifically on Windows 7 similarity and others are just decent window managers to help with tiling. There are well over 20 available and reviewed here.

Comment: This is close - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16217/window-management-app-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

[FinderMinder](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) resizes Finder windows when they are opened. There is a small delay before windows are resized and you have to keep it running on the background though.

[image]

I use this script to reset the properties of windows manually:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if number of windows is 0 then return
    tell Finder window 1
        set toolbar visible to false
        set sidebar width to 0
        set statusbar visible to false
        set current view to column view
        set bounds to {474, 250, 1318, 750}
        tell its column view options
            set shows icon to false
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

When you move or resize a window, Finder saves its dimensions to a .DS_Store file. You can make all folders use the default dimensions by deleting .DS_Store files:

```
sudo find / -name .DS_Store -delete && killall Finder
```

It also removes Spotlight comments, resets the positions of icons in icon view, and removes folder-specific sorting modes and view options.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "repositioning, sizing" your windows? Are they always appearing in the wrong location, at the wrong size so you have to fuss with them and get them the way you like?

If so, the solution is built-in to the Finder. Close all but one Finder window and put it where you want it. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to show the view options window (fuss with any settings you want in there), and hit "Use as Defaults". Then close the options window and the Finder window and your settings should stick.

One caveat: any folder window for which you've set a position/size will open at that preset size and ignore your defaults. Just move it to the right position and it should stay there. If it doesn't, close it, delete the `.DS_Store` file from the Terminal, and reopen - it should then obey your defaults.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a way of arranging a window to fill any of the sides of the screen, [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) is the most popular choice.

You can find [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x) a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

**Finder Window Manager** "FWM" is an excellent app that saves window setups (snapshots). Go [here](http://www.jonn8.com/fwm/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) should be mentioned in this context.
Very capable little app. Save window layout snapshots, move windows, resize them etc.
It's $10, well worth the price.