# Maximise window in OS X only using App Store extention

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, window-manager

We know maximise a window in OS X (like we do in Ubuntu Unity or MS Windows) is not currently possible.

Are there any third party extensions available from OS X App Store to achieve this?

(I don't want to install applications that are not in App store for security reasons.)

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/557/can-i-get-windows-7-like-window-resizing-on-mac-os-x as well

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because of app store query.

Comment: Noted - good edit. Let's see what others have for answers in addition to Divvy...

Answer (score 1):

Get [Divvy - Window Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12) app for your specific use case.

It will let you maximize windows in the more traditional sense of taking all the screen space. It's solid, secure, reliable and can do many, many other things in addition to maximizing. There are many others on the store, but if you [search this site for Divvy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=divvy) - you'll see it has wide acclaim and utility.

You could do worse than choosing Moom as well.

- https://manytricks.com/moom/

Comment: I tried Divvy but there seems to be no way of maximising windows using mouse clicks. But maximisation works with key combination.

Comment: @DUKE It likely won't be possible for a MAS app to over-ride the organic buttons since there likely isn't a public API to change that behavior.

Comment: I finally find an application called "Cinch" in the app store. Simply dragging the tittle bar of the window to the top of the screen will maximise the window. Probably easier than clicking the small green button.