# How do i rescale a window in in all 4 directions?

Tags: windows

I'd like to minimize/maximize any generic window in all 4 directions. How do I accomplish this?

More specifically, I'd like to do this for iterm, but it would be nice if the solution is generic.

Comment: Are you looking for window management recommendations like [moom](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303909/5472) or [divvy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/134748/5472)

Comment: Have you tried pressing Option+Command while resizing the window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maximise a window to fill up screen in Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115895/how-to-maximise-a-window-to-fill-up-screen-in-mavericks) Especially see my answer, just added, with as far as I'm aware the only way to do this *properly* in all apps.